# Script to upload a URL and download the end result, including the specific errors

Tags: url, vbscript, download

I adapted the code below to try to get my listing to show results of going to the URL and writing the results to the list that I could then match up in excel after (manually).

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
File = "C:\Users\212708488\Desktop\Project Bacon\Excellist.txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(File)
FileNumber = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    URLFromList = objFile.ReadLine
    FileNumber = FileNumber + 1
    if download(URLFromList, "test" & FileNumber & ".txt", false) then
        wscript.echo "download ok for " & URLFromList
    else
        wscript.echo "download did not work for " & URLFromList
    end if
Loop
objFile.Close
objFSO = Nothing
```

If you can lead me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.
Thank you!!

Comment: What's the problem with the current code?

Comment: You should not include 'thank' in posts. See this meta post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: Can you explain what's this line `if download(URLFromList, "test" & FileNumber & ".txt", false) then` ? If this is a function ? i can't see it in your code ?